# How to stub mock data for below AWS SSM code

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, aws-sdk, sinon, aws-ssm

```js
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
let ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: 'uk-west-1' });

function abc(path) {
  let p = {
    Path: path,
    WithDecryption: true,
  };
  let res = {};
  let d = await ssm.getParametersByPath(p).promise();
  res['Parameters'] = d.Parameters;
  while (d.NextToken) {
    p.NextToken = d.NextToken;
    d = await ssm.getParametersByPath(p).promise();
    res['Parameters'] = d.Parameters;
  }

  return res;
}
```

I have tried to stub but it's always giving me { Parameters: [] } response .

can anyone help me with this, please

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 , Can you please help me with this .

Comment: "I have tried to stub", provide this part.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and some variables are missing such as `params` and `ssmclient `